# SQL Query - How to find out how which employees worked at more than one store

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a relationship table such that it has

```
employeeID | storeID
```

What would be the query to find out which employees worked at more than one store?

```
SELECT employeeID WHERE ???
```

And possibly also list each different stores just once per employee...

Comment: And possibly also list the different stores (just once each).

Comment: What is your DB and table structure? Please also post what you've tried so far.

Comment: You're looking for COUNT, GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: @hkf I'm not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: @StephaneGrenier Corbin has the right answer

Comment: If you understood general concepts you should have somewhere to begin with. Let us know how you get on and where exactly you are stuck. "GIEF CODEZ NAO PLOX" is highly frowned upon.

Comment: No offense, but err...  This possibly the simplest use of GROUP by an an aggregate function that there is.

Comment: @hkf It's an sql query. Either you're dead on or it's almost impossible to know where you're failing. And there's so many different ways to attack. Honestly, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here by just flaming me.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier A good starting point would be to see the following article http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php Then you can try it out and show SO the query if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AmitBhargava it's mostly the getting the count of stores that's causing me grief and not so much the group by.

Comment: @Corbin I disagree. So far two answers and neither works correctly.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier because your question did not state all of the specifications.  We all assumed that (employee_id, store_id) were unique pairs, though the last sentence does imply now that I reread it.

Comment: @Corbin relationship table generally don't mean unique pairs. And yes the last sentence builds on that. If I wanted to be smug, I could say you weren't reading the specs/requirements correctly. It's frustrating to be attacked for a question that's not really that simple an sql select query.

Comment: The difficulty of the question is not why we all criticized it.  Your question shows absolutely no effort at all to do anything yourself, and it comes across as a requirement, not as a question.  Like a client to a coder requirement.  (As OMG Ponies noted).  Also, if I wanted to be smug, I could point out how your question says "And possibly also".  It's apparently optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`, as in:

```
select employeeID, count(*) from table group by employeeID having count(distinct storeID) > 1
```

This will give you the employees working at more than one store.  Use this as a subquery to list the stores for each such employee.

Comment: Actually the count(*) included duplicate stores. So for example if employee Bob worked 3 times at store 1, the count was 3 and not 1...

Comment: So very close!! The end shoudl be count(distinct storeID) and not count(*). I'll edit your answer and select it

Answer (score 1):

you can try -

```
select distinct employeeID,StoreID from table1
where storeID in 
(
select storeID from table1 group by storeID having count(distinct employeeID) >1
)
```

cor storing count and showing store ID also in one query you can use following query..

```
select a.employeeID,a.storeID,b.cnt
from table1 a,
    (select employeeID,count(*) cnt 
       from table1 
   group by employeeID 
     having count(distinct storeID) >1) b
where a.employeID=b.employeeid
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the store count too?

Comment: Btw, your first query seems to have somewhat worked but is missing data. For example, it did find employees that worked in more than one store, but not all of them...

Comment: I think it should be SELECT employeeID from table1 grouped by employeeID having count (distinct storeID) > 1

Comment: you asked to list down all the store as well .. if you want to know about stores as well then you have to select stores also .. right ?